# solve the following simultaneous equations for x and y and show whether the solution exists or not? 30x+3y≅ 0(mod37) and y≅ 4+13x(mod37)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

solve the following simultaneous equations for x and y and show whether the solution exists or not?(show in particular that what division you must carry out to solve each case) 
30x+3y≅ 0(mod37) and y≅ 4+13x(mod37) 
Are we supposed to use substitution in equations having congruence sign the same way we use substitution in equations having equals to sign?
I am unable to do this on my own.
please help!

Comment: Yes you can proceed with substitution. Actually, you have to make the calculations in the field $\mathbf Z/37\mathbf Z$. The rest is exactly as in the more familiar linear systems in $\mathbf R$ (substitution or Gauß' pivot method).

Comment: can you please give me some more explanation.

Comment: if I proceed with normal substitution , how should I deal with mod37?

Answer (score -1):

we have $$30x+3y\equiv 0 \mod 37$$ and $$y\equiv 4+13x\mod 37$$ thus we have $$30x+3(4+13x)\equiv 0\mod 37$$ and this is equivalent to $$69x\equiv -12 \mod 37$$ from here we get 
$$x\equiv -\frac{12}{69}=-\frac{4}{23}\equiv \frac{736}{23}\equiv 32 \mod 37$$

Comment: and is y ≅ 420mod37?